# Yii2 rest api не записывает данные

Tags: yii2, rest

Методом POST записываю данные, а в ответ создаёт только id. В чём проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: естественно проблема в коде, не ждите что вам помогут если вы не предоставили никакой полезной информации кроме факта что у вас что-то не работает

Comment: Возможно валидация не отрабатывает или полей нет в рулсах.

Answer (score 0):

как минимум это может быть связано с блоком "rules" в модели

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       ...
       [['name','author'], 'safe'],
       ...
    ];
}
```